# Is the right-handed antineutrino the CPT conjugate of the left-handed neutrino?

Tags: neutrinos, electroweak, majorana-fermions, cpt-symmetry

I am working from the book Massive Neutrinos in Physics and Astrophysics by Mohapatra and Pal (which is available [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Q6pfFwIZcPgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=massive%20neutrinos%20in%20physics%20and%20astrophysics%20books&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIv5uZyrvdxwIV4WnbCh1-LAip#v=onepage&q=massive%20neutrinos%20in%20physics%20and%20astrophysics%20books&f=false)). On page 66, the authors claim that $\psi_{L}$ is the $\mathcal{CPT}$ conjugate of $\hat{\psi}_R$ (where the hat means antiparticle).

I have attempted to verify this using the Weyl basis and equation 4.60 on page 64 by the following method:
Take the Dirac spinor to be
$$
\psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\chi\\
-i\sigma_{2}\phi^{*}
\end{array}\right)
$$
and the charge conjugation operator (except for phase factors)
$$
\mathcal{C}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 &i\sigma_{2} \\
-i\sigma_{2} & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Using this I find $$
\psi_{L}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\chi\\
0
\end{array}\right),
\hat{\psi}_{R}=R\hat{\psi}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0\\
-i \sigma_{2} \chi^{*}
\end{array}\right)
$$
and the $\mathcal{CPT}$ conjugate of $\psi_{L}$ is (up to a phase)$$
-\gamma_{5}\psi^*_L = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\chi^*\\
0
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\chi^*\\
0
\end{array}\right)
$$
But this is nothing like my expression for $\hat{\psi}_R$.

Where am I going wrong?